# What object(s) are the Number(), parseInt() and parseFloat() functions a member of in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, numbers, parseint, parsefloat

I know that in JavaScript, the `Number()`, `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` methods can be invoked without specifying the object they are a member of.

For example, `alert()` is part of the `window` object. You can call `window.alert()` but you can also omit the `window.` part and it will still work.

But what object(s) are the `Number()`, `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` functions a member of?

Comment: There is no object when calling `Number(5)` or `parseInt("3")`.

Comment: For example the method alert() belongs to the window object and the method write() to the document object. Number(), parseInt() and parseFloat() have to have object because the basic structure is: objectname.methodname()

Comment: There is always an object. A lot of times you don't write window.alert(), only alert() because it isn't necessary write the object in this case. With Number()......occurs the same. But they have an object

Comment: No, for local variables there is no object. Only for some global variables, they are *also* accessible as properties of the global object - and in fact, `parseInt`, `alert`, `Number` and `parseFloat` work the same in that regard. Have you tried `window.parseInt("3")`?

Answer (score 0):

`Number()`, `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` are all part of the [global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object)<sup>[[spec]](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-global-object)</sup>. In browsers this is the [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object.

```js
console.log(window.Number === Number);
console.log(window.parseInt === parseInt);
console.log(window.parseFloat === parseFloat);
```

Any member of the global object can be accessed without explicitly adding `window.`.

Answer (score -1):

The three methods are global methods (see [w3schools1](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_number_methods.asp), [w3schools2](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_global.asp)), which are functions that are available to any script as they are not methods of any specific object (see [docs.microfocus.com](https://docs.microfocus.com/SM/9.60/Codeless/Content/programming/javascript/reference/list_javascript_global_methods.htm))

Comment: I have taken a look to w3school but it doesn't talk about global methods. The another website you comment gives a small explanation and show a list but these methods aren't in it. It sounds strange for me because these methods i indicate are quite specific, since they refer to a numbers.

Comment: Then please look again the w3schools link. In section "*Converting Variables to Numbers*" you will find: "**These methods are not number methods, but global JavaScript methods.**". I added another w3schools link. Read it and you will find there a list of global functions with the three in it. The microfocus link explains the object part of your question

Comment: I have read it and they are global functions. But they can also work like methods of the Number object. Ej: document.write(Number.parseInt("75")+3);

Comment: In fact in this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt say This method has the same functionality as the global parseInt() function:

Number.parseInt === parseInt // true

Comment: If you are still not satisfied with these answers you should reformulate your question...